# Facebook REST Api with OAuth tokens

Tags: facebook, rest, oauth

As described in the [Facebook Auth guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/upgrade#permissions), I'm able to make (most) old REST API calls with OAuth tokens

i.e.

```
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?
    method=friends.get&
    app_id=...&
    v=1.0&
    call_id=...&
    sig=...
```

becomes

```
https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?
    method=friends.get&
    token=...
```

This does NOT work with the method "admin.setAppProperties". I get an "Application does not have permission for this action" error. The OAuth token I have though, has granted every available permission including offline access to my app, however. Any clue whats going on? Facebook docs and forums are characteristically mum.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't managed to fix it yet, I've found the problem with their documentation:

the parameter name for the access token is wrong: it is "access_token" and not "token"

```
https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?
    method=friends.get&
    access_token=...
```